# About Exercise 5.B.20 in "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler.

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

I am reading "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler.

> Exercise 5.B.20:
> Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional complex vector space and $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$. Prove that $T$ has an invariant subspace of dimension $k$ for each $k=1,\dots,\dim V$.

$V$ and $\{0\}$ are trivial invariant subspaces of $T$.

The author didn't write as follows:

> Exercise 5.B.20:
> Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional complex vector space and $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$. Prove that $T$ has an invariant subspace of dimension $k$ for each $k=0,\dots,\dim V$.

The author didn't write as follows:

> Exercise 5.B.20:
> Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional complex vector space and $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$. Prove that $T$ has an invariant subspace of dimension $k$ for each $k=1,\dots,\dim V-1$.

Any reason?

If I were the zero dimensional vector space, I would say to the author "Why did you exclude me?".

Comment: Maybe It is written like that because these cases are trivial and there is nothing to prove.

Comment: @Marcos Thank you very much for your comment. But $V$ is also trivial. The author didn't exclude $k=\dim V$. It is unfair.